# Multiprocessing in wxpython

Tags: python-2.7, wxpython, python-multithreading, python-multiprocessing

I have a GUI with buttons 'OK' and 'Cancel' clicking on which creates a child threads which pops up a dialog box saying 'OK/Cancel button is pressed'. Now when i click on OK button, i want child thread calling it must wait for another process(may be another dialogbox saying wait) and then must pop up message 'OK button is pressed'.
I used wx.timer for childthread to wait but could not get it worked.

How to make a child thread pause and continue(like an interrupt) when the process is done? 
Below find my trials!

```
import wx, time
from threading import Thread

ID_RUN = 101
ID_RUN2 = 102


class ChildThread_OK(Thread):
    def __init__(self, myframe):
    """Init Worker Thread Class."""
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.myframe = myframe
        self._want_abort = True

    def run(self):
        if self._want_abort is True:
        self.waitevent()
        wx.CallAfter(self.myframe.AfterRun, 'Ok button pressed')

    def waitevent(self):
        wx.CallAfter(self.myframe.message,"Oops!!there is another process running wait for it to finish. Closing this dialog box in 2s...")

    def closeit(self, event):
        self.dialogBox.Destroy()

class ChildThread_Cancel(Thread):
    def __init__(self, myframe):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.myframe = myframe

    def run(self):
        wx.CallAfter(self.myframe.AfterRun, "Cancel button pressed")


class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, ID, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, ID, title)
        panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)
        mainSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        mainSizer.Add(wx.Button(panel, ID_RUN, "OK"))
        mainSizer.Add(wx.Button(panel, ID_RUN2, "Cancel"))
         panel.SetSizer(mainSizer)
        mainSizer.Fit(self)
        wx.EVT_BUTTON(self, ID_RUN, self.onRun)
        wx.EVT_BUTTON(self, ID_RUN2, self.onRun2)

    def onRun(self, event):
        self.child = ChildThread_OK(myframe=self)
        self.child.daemon = True
        self.child.start()

    def onRun2(self, event):
        self.child2 = ChildThread_Cancel(myframe = self)
        self.child2.daemon = True
        self.child2.start()

    def AfterRun(self, msg):
        dlg = wx.MessageDialog(self, msg, "Message", wx.OK | wx.ICON_INFORMATION)
        dlg.ShowModal()
        dlg.Destroy()

    def message(self,msg):
        dlg = wx.BusyInfo(msg)
        time.sleep(5)

class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        frame = MyFrame(None, -1, "My GUI")
        frame.Show(True)
        frame.Centre()
        return True

app = MyApp(0)
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: And yeah how to make a child thread to pause it's execution for a while and then continue?

Answer (score 0):

First: You cannot use timer or message box in a child thread, you can only use them in main thread. So the methods below are not meaningful.

```
def waitevent(self):
    self.timer = wx.Timer(self, 1)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.closeit, self.timer)
    self.timer.Start(2000, wx.TIMER_ONE_SHOT)
    wx.CallAfter(self.AfterRun, 'Ok button pressed')
    print 'Oops!!there is another process running wait for it to finish. Closing this dialog box in 2s...'

def closeit(self, event):
    self.dialogBox.Destroy()
```

Second: If you use message boxes to display something, main thread is suspended and your code after message box is run after message box is closed. You can use wx.StaticText or wx.TextCtrl on main panel to show the messages or you can create new frames mimicing message boxes and they dont suspend the program and can be easily destroyed OR you can make a custom message dialog waiting for a variable to change (e.g. True/False). There is a custom message dialog example in wxPython demo.

Third: You should learn the events and queues in python's multithreading module to help you control the child threads. Child thread can sleep until an event is set or can wait until there is something in a queue.

Comment: I'm learning queue and events in multithreading module.I will get back to you if i have any doubt once i implement  it. Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: My another question is, is it possible to make a the whole execution stops for a while and then continue ??eg.,like breakpoints we use in debugging.The process until breakpoint runs but after that doesn't run.It continues only after the breakpoint is removed.Can u show me this concept with example if u don't mind!

Comment: Dont think about pausing GUI application's main thread because it becomes unresponsive. If you want to pause child threads or another console program, the best know way is to use sleep function from time module. If you want to pause your child threads, you can put a loop in run method and call sleep function in it or you can wait for an event set (that is in threading module). You can pause execution until event is set. There are tons of examples if you google it. Here is a [link](https://pymotw.com/2/threading/) for you

Comment: i came across threading.Event() method.Is it possible to pause a execution of child thread using this in above code scenario?